# svn difference between Setup-Subversion-1.6.X.msi and svn-python-1.6.X.win32-pyX.X.exe install

Tags: svn, installation

I have just started working at a new place and they don't have any version control at all. I'm very anxious to get some source control up and running quickly and I have been researching setting up SVN. I need to set up SVN on the same IIS server we use for development, so I don't want to install apache if I don't have too, running two web servers on one box seems like a road to conflicts and hair loss.

Where I'm really at a loss is the difference between
Setup-Subversion-1.6.X.msi
and
svn-python-1.6.X.win32-pyX.X.exe?
The documentation on the website seems geared towards developers of SVN.

I also can't find any information about the differences between windows installs of SVN.
http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows
Are they different installers, or completely different implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Setup-Subversion-1.6.X.msi` is the Subversion installer and will allow you to install the Subversion server and client.

`svn-python-1.6.X.win32-pyX.X.exe` is an installer for the Subversion Python bindings - these allow you to interact with Subversion repositories from Python.

For getting Subversion up and running quickly you'll only need the Subversion installer - this will install [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html), which is an easy way of serving a Subversion repository that doesn't require Apache or IIS.

1.6.12 is the latest version of Subversion. Do you actually have an installer called `Setup-Subversion-1.6.X.msi`? If so then it's an old 'official' installer, and you can't get these any more (official binaries stopped at 1.6.6).

The installers listed [here](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows) are indeed different installers, produced by different companies, and aren't official. I don't know if they modify Subversion itself, but in some cases they bundle additional software, e.g. the Apache web server and [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) (for browsing repositories using a web browser). [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) might be what you want as it seems to be a 'basic' Subversion package, and includes svnserve.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I don't have a Setup-Subversion-1.6.X.msi I was just trying to make my post more generic. Looks like if I just follow Jeff Atwood's blog post I'll be fine. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html